# strings is showing output by splitting a line into two

Tags: string, oracle, shell, spfile

```
oracle$ strings spfilesid.ora |grep LOCATION
*.log_archive_dest_1='LOCATION=/oraprod/sid/

oracle$ strings spfilesid.ora |less
*.log_archive_dest_1='LOCATION=/oraprod/sid/
flash_recovery_area/archivelog'
```

The output of strings command is getting split into two lines.
Do not think this is a problem with width of the screen.

Re-created spfile and still have the same issue.

Created pfile from the spfile and the pfile shows the value in single line.

Db shows (via sqlplus and show parameter) value in absolute path and in one line.

what is the reason for strings splitting the line into two?
how to fix it?

Comment: Why is this a problem?  Technically, the spfile is a binary file that is not designed to be human readable (though, of course, we know that it is basically human readable).  Why are you using strings against the spfile in the first place?  Could you just query `v$parameter` instead?

Comment: I know it and already mentioned it in my post (show parameter or v$parameter).
For now, it is not something I can move away from using strings.

Comment: Then it's probably not something that can be fixed.  Binary files may store things differently than files that are intended to be human readable.  The "strings" command has no idea how to interpret the binary contents of the file so it finds a control character that Oracle knows is part of the file format not the data string.  Either use a human readable pfile or use one of the interfaces designed for querying parameters.